# Reactnative error - expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: react-native

I am hitting this error when i am trying to define my own custom components.

```
// /common/MyAppText.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'ReactNative';

class MyAppText extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>hello</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default MyAppText
```

On the other app, i tried to import it and use it by

```
import MyAppText from './common/MyAppText'
class Home extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <MyAppText />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

But i hit the error "expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined, please check render method of 'MyAppText'. Anyone can see what is wrong with the export syntax?

If i defined everything in the same document then it works, so it is something with the export that i couldn't figure out.

Comment: Your own export/import looks fine. Not sure if this is the issue, but the line `import {..} from 'ReactNative` should be `from 'react-native'`. I would expect that to crash with a different error though, unless you for some reason also have a module called `ReactNative` somewhere.

Comment: Ah, actually it's probably importing the React renderer shim thanks to this globally available Haste module: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6be550d85c29a6ded32dcfe1330577c202da9073/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNative.js#L9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own export/import looks fine.  Not sure if this is the issue, but the line

```
import {..} from 'ReactNative';
```

Should be:

```
import {..} from 'react-native';
```

You might expect that to crash with a different error (module not found), but since [this internal React Native file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6be550d85c29a6ded32dcfe1330577c202da9073/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNative.js#L9) exports a globally available module "ReactNative" via Haste, your import ends up picking that file. Because that file doesn't export properties `View` and `Text`, the code compiles fine, but ends up with undefined variables.

*Edit for more context*:

The React Native bundler (called [Metro](https://github.com/facebook/metro-bundler)) uses Facebook's own module system (called Haste), which allows anybody to decorate a file with a comment `@providesModule Name`, and then import it from globally anywhere with just `import ... from 'Name';`

One of the internal renderer modules declares `@providesModule ReactNative`. So when you've imported `from 'ReactNative'`, you got that module instead of a build error.

Comment: yes you are right. The issue was with the misspelling of react-native. Not sure why it didn't throw an error with the wrong package name.

Comment: I expanded on that in the answer - it's a bit arcane, but perfectly logical :)